# Gparted can no create extended type or name partition

Tags: filesystems, partition, storage, gparted

I have a 300gb hd with linux installed. It has a two partitions. The primary 30gb partition where the OS is installed. In addition, it has another primary partition that is 15gb. Then it has 236gb unallocated.

When I select the unallocated space in gparted and select partition>new

under the "create as" dropdown box, I can only select "logical" type for the new partition. Both primary and extended are greyed out. In addition I can not enter a partition name, as this field is also disabled and greyed out.

What is going on here?

Comment: Did you experience the same issue when booting from a live system (Live-CD)? Maybe you have to unmount the disk first (what can be difficult when running as your system disk)?

Comment: I don't think that is the case, because I think I made the second extended partition while the drive was mounted.